# $_request ["request"] in a restful api

Tags: php, restful-url

I am learning to program a restful api and I am confused about some code in this tutorial.

http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/

They used

`$_REQUEST["request"]`

for the request uri. I am trying to understand the reason why I'd do this instead of

`$_SERVER["request_uri"]`

Comment: extra explanation not make statement large

Comment: I was just curious about what the tutorial was trying to accomplish by using $_REQUEST["request"] but if you look at the answer I have posted it clears up everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I spent soooo little time reading the .htaccess code that it all just made no sense.

So here is the synopsis:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This **RewriteRule** states that anything requested at the path of **api/vi/(.*)** will be redirected to the path **api/v1/api.php?request=$1**. The variable it adds at the end is the request variable we use the **$_REQUEST["request"]** to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

theThe $_REQUEST call gets the value of a variable called 'request' from either a GET or a POST (only GET accepted in the tutorial). $_SERVER["request_uri"] fetches the URI given to access the page

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Why would I want to get the request variable instead of a uri? Isn't the uri the path I'd want to parse into variables like endpoint and verb so that I can construct the right response?